# How to pass variables from freemaker template to xml file

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I am not able to pass a variable with value to xml file.

I have tried the using dollar sign to retrieve the value, but no success.

```
<#if loyaltyModel.getTotalPoints()?? && loyaltyModel.getTotalPoints().getAmount()?has_content>
    <div class="loyalty-banner"><#global loyaltyPoints=loyaltyModel.getTotalPoints().getAmount() >
        <#if loyaltyModel.getLoyaltyBannerUrl()?? && loyaltyModel.getLoyaltyBannerUrl()?has_content>
            <img src="${loyaltyModel.getLoyaltyBannerUrl()}" alt="Marriott Loyalty"/>
        </#if>
        <div class="loyalty-text"><#global points=loyaltyModel.getTotalPoints().getAmount() />
            <#if loyaltyModel.getLoyaltyBannerTextMsg()?? && loyaltyModel.getLoyaltyBannerTextMsg()?has_content>
                ${loyaltyModel.getLoyaltyBannerTextMsg()}
            </#if>
        </div>
    </div>
</#if>
```

I want to passs the value of "loyaltyPoints" to an xml.
Kindly help.

Comment: _but no success_ Are you saying that you are not getting the expected output? If so, then please post the output you are getting and also the output you expect to get. Also, you have posted your _FreeMarker_ template. The problem may lie with your data-model which should be implemented in java code. Maybe you need to post that java code as well?

Comment: @Abra the expected output is "10000" where as m getting an output put like "${loyaltyPoints}"

Comment: Post your java code, please.

Comment: just a template, Please let me know a psedo code for trasferring data from ftl to xml. Please post the minimum code required.

Comment: Have you read the [FreeMarker manual](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/index.html)? There are also many online tutorials including [Using FreeMarker templates](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/FreeMarker/article.html)